# Wireshark saving filter result

Tags: http, filter, wireshark

I have a pcap file captured from a network. Now everytime I try to view the HTTP packets I place "http" in the filter. Is there a way where I can only save the HTTP filtered packets and not the lower level protocols included in the packet such as TCP, IP, Ethernet, Frames.

Answer (score 1):

Try [exporting](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOExportSection.html) rather than saving. There is an option there for exporting only selected packets.

Comment: Tnx, I tried export before but didn't get what I wanted, I gave it another try but this time I did tried to play with it File>Export>File... then below there is a Packet Range section I clicked on "Selected Packet" and "Displayed" then click save.

Comment: [Expand](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChWorkDisplayPopUpSection.html#ChWorkPacketDetailsPanePopUpMenu) only HTP in the [Packet Details](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChUsePacketDetailsPaneSection.html) pane, before exporting the file.